# Bypassing a faces converter for certain properties in JSF

Tags: jsf, converters, jsf-2.2

I have a converter as follows to trim all leading and trailing white spaces and strip additional spaces between words.

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
@FacesConverter(forClass=String.class)
public final class StringTrimmer implements Converter
{
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
    {
        return value != null ? value.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ") : null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
    {
        return value!=null ? ((String) value).trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ") : null;
    }
}
```

This converter is applied globally to all string type properties in associated backing beans.

Sometimes it is necessary to bypass this converter for certain properties like "password" in which no white spaces or additional spaces between words should be trimmed or striped respectively.

How can such string type properties be bypassed so that this converter is not applied to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways.

1. Explicitly declare a converter which does effectively nothing with the value.

   E.g.

   ```
   <h:inputSecret ... converter="noConverter" />
   ```

   with

   ```
   @FacesConverter("noConverter")
   public class NoConverter implements Converter {

       @Override
       public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
           return value;
       }

       @Override
       public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
           return (value != null) ? value.toString() : ""; // This is what EL would do "under the covers" when there's no converter.
       }

   }
   ```

   ---
2. Pass an additional component attribute and let the converter check that.

   ```
   <h:inputSecret ...>
       <f:attribute name="skipConverter" value="true" />
   </h:inputSecret>
   ```

   with

   ```
   @Override
   public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
       if (Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(component.getAttributes().get("skipConverter")))) {
           return value;
       }

       // Original code here.
   }

   @Override
   public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
       if (Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(component.getAttributes().get("skipConverter")))) {
           return (value != null) ? value.toString() : "";
       }

       // Original code here.
   }
   ```

   ---
3. Let the converter check the component type. The `UIComponent` behind `<h:inputSecret>` is an instance of the [`HtmlInputSecret`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlInputSecret.html) class.

   ```
   @Override
   public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
       if (component instanceof HtmlInputSecret) {
           return value;
       }

       // Original code here.
   }

   @Override
   public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
       if (component instanceof HtmlInputSecret) {
           return (value != null) ? value.toString() : "";
       }

       // Original code here.
   }
   ```

Which way to use depends on business requirements and degree of reusability of the converter.